# Access select2 HTML options from knockout custom binding in order to disable them

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I am trying to access the option elements from a select2 dropdown list using a Knockout custom binding in order to disable some of them (some of the options). The custom binding is:

```
    ko.bindingHandlers.select2 = {
        after: ["options", "value"],
        update: function (el, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
            var select2 = $(el).data("select2");
        }
    };
```

and the HTML part is:

```
    <div style="width: 350px;">
        <select style="width: 100%;" data-bind="value: attributiSelezionati, options: data, valueAllowUnset: true, optionsText: 'text', optionsValue: 'id', select2: { placeholder: 'Select an option...', allowClear: true, multiple: true}"></select>
    </div>
```

where the data array is:

```
this.data = ko.observableArray([]);
this.data.push(new Item(1, "Item 1"));
this.data.push(new Item(2, "Item 2"));
this.data.push(new Item(2, "Item 22"));
this.data.push(new Item(3, "Item 3"));
this.data.push(new Item(null, "Item 4"));

class Item {
id: KnockoutObservable<number> = ko.observable<number>();
text: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>();

constructor(Id: number, Text: string) {
    this.id(Id);
    this.text(Text);
} 
}
```

I can see the data when I hover over the el element but I do not know how to access it programmatically. Does anyone know how to get these items?[image: The options to retrieve]

Answer (score 0):

> It should be in `valueAccessor()`

valueAccessor: This represents a JavaScript function that can be used to access the current property or expression involved in this binding. Because Knockout allows you to use either a view model property directly (such as "data-bind='enabled: isEnabled'"), or an expression (such as "data-bind='enabled: firstName.length > 0'"), there's a utility function that will "unwrap" and give you the actual value used in the binding. Incidentally, this function is called "ko.unwrap."

```
var val = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
//val.options;
```